# XSD: xs:entity and xs:entities -- my entity works as an attribute but fails as an element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have written a XSD and a conforming XML and now want to use predefined entities. Problem is that as soon as I use the xs:entity type, my XML elements are no longer conform to the XSD. My entity attributes work fine, but elements break.

I have the following minimal example of an XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
 targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/xsdSimpleTypes"
 xmlns:st="http://www.example.com/xsdSimpleTypes">

  <xs:element name='simpleTypes' type="st:SimpleTypesType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="SimpleTypesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- string -->
      <xs:element name="test_ENTITIES" type="ENTITIES"/>
      <xs:element name="test_ENTITY" type="ENTITY"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute use="required" name="test_ENTITIES" type="ENTITIES"/>
    <xs:attribute use="required" name="test_ENTITY" type="ENTITY"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and the following minimal XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE schema [
<!ENTITY all_is_ok "all_is_ok">
]>
<st:simpleTypes xmlns:st="http://www.example.com/xsdSimpleTypes"
    test_ENTITIES="&all_is_ok;"
    test_ENTITY="&all_is_ok;">
    <test_ENTITIES>&all_is_ok;</test_ENTITIES>
    <test_ENTITY>&all_is_ok;</test_ENTITY>
</st:simpleTypes>
```

:: when I validate the xml against the XSD, libxml doesn't like the elements but the attributes are ok. (when I change the attributes content it also breaks, so it IS validating them :)

---

EDIT:
I don't really wanna change the xsd. I want to make the XML conform. By changing values I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use xs:ENTITY or xs:ENTITIES to use entity references in character content. The entities are expanded and the expanded content is checked against the declared type of the element, whether or not it is declared using xs:ENTITY.

In fact xs:ENTITY is only for use when the value is the name of an *unparsed entity*. I don't know why it's accepting your attribute values, because you have no unparsed entities in your DTD - only parsed entities.

Comment: ok, then what would be valid content for the xs:Entity / xs:Entities type? It wants an entity of some sort :) [I can't change the xsd]

Comment: Valid content would be if you changed `<!ENTITY all_is_ok "all_is_ok">` to `<!ENTITY all_is_ok SYSTEM "http://example.org/pic.jpg" NDATA jpeg>`